# Webpage not visible completely with Selenium Automation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having very tough time as I am writing code in eclipse using Selenium for IE11. I am using Java.

After writing such commands such as:

**mydriver.findElement(By.name("XXXXX")).click();**
My webpage focused is lost and focus is on the current element in question.

**That means, if the element is on right side and i perform some action on this element (using above command, for example)... Left side is not visible and there is no scrollbar also available for me to use left scroll command.**

I have to use below Refresh command again and again to get the full webpage back: 
**mydriver.navigate().refresh();**

I have used commands such as:
1) mydriver.manage().window().maximize();---  in start once.
2) myWaitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("XXX")));--- as per requirements waiting for element on webpage.

Please advise.

Comment: You can use javaScriptexecutor to make the webelemnt into the view and then perform any operation on that

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the site you are working on. Please post a link to an example page and the code you are using and the specific behavior on that page.

Comment: I think the site should work normally when operate by manual,  seems the selenium action not trigger browser repainting correctly,  I doubt the issue comes from IEDriver,  have you tried latest or other IEDriver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`JavascriptExecutor`** to bring back the **focus** on the window with the following line of code :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```